# Cannot access the state but i see it on debbugger

Tags: reactjs, api, react-native, state, native

*I have function to fetch my data, and i do `setState` to put my data inside my state.*

But i dont understand how to use it in my `render()`

```
getFixture = async () => {
    const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:80/testmatch/get_fixture.php';
    fetch(url).then((reponse) => reponse.json())
        .then((reponseJson) => { 
           this.setState({
                data:reponseJson,
                isLoading:false
            })
        })
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.getFixture()
    }
```

if i do a `console.log(this.state.data);` in my render is show me this in the console (in image join)

if i do `console.log(this.state.data.elapsed);` is working and i get the value but if i do  `console.log(this.state.data.awayTeam.logo);` i get ***Cannot read property 'logo'***

I dont understand why.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvlXi.png)

Here is all the code, that i want is to use all datas from my data State to my render :

```
getFixture = async () => {
        const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:80/testmatch/get_fixture.php';
         fetch(url).then((reponse) => reponse.json())
        .then((reponseJson) => { 
           this.setState({
                data:reponseJson,
                isLoading:false
            })
           console.log(this.state.data.awayTeam.logo); // WORKING (SHOW ME THE LINK)
        })
    }



render() {
   console.log(this.state.data.awayTeam.logo); // NOT WORKING (CANNOT READ PROPERTY OF UNDEFINED)
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
         <View style={styles.containerScore}>
            <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', borderColor:'#171F33',borderBottomWidth: 1 }}>

              <View style={{flex: 1,paddingTop:7,paddingBottom:7}}>
                 <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                 <Image style={{width: 50, height: 50}} source={{uri: "toto"}} />
                </View>
              </View>

              <View style={{flex: 1,paddingTop:7,paddingBottom:7, backgroundColor:'#fff'}}>
               <Text style={{fontSize:13}}> {this.state.data.elapsed}</Text>
              </View>

              <View style={{flex: 1,paddingTop:7,paddingBottom:7, marginLeft:2, backgroundColor:'#000'}}>
               <Text style={{fontSize:13}}></Text>
              </View>

            </View>

          <Text style={{color:"#FFF"}}>{} </Text>
         </View>

         <View style={styles.containerInfo}>


           <ScrollableTabView style={{marginTop: 1}} initialPage={0} renderTabBar={() => <CustomTabBar/>} >

            <View tabLabel='Tab #1'>
             <Text>My</Text>
            </View>

            <View tabLabel='Tab #2'>
            <Text>favorite</Text>
            </View>

            <View tabLabel='Tab #3'>
            <Text>favorite</Text>
            </View>

            <View tabLabel='Tab #4'>
            <Text>favorite</Text>
            </View>

            </ScrollableTabView>
         </View>
      </View>




    );
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the initial render, the this.state.data is not yet set, so if you try to access it without null checking it will give you an error.

In your jsx, you can check if this.state.data is falsy and if it is falsy return immediately like this:

```
  render() {

    if (!this.state.data) {
      return (<View><Text>Loading...</Text></View>);
    }

    console.log(this.state.data.awayTeam.logo); 

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
         <View style={styles.containerScore}>
            <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', borderColor:'#171F33',borderBottomWidth: 1 }}>
              <View style={{flex: 1,paddingTop:7,paddingBottom:7}}>
                 <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                 <Image style={{width: 50, height: 50}} source={{uri: "toto"}} />
                </View>
              </View>
              <View style={{flex: 1,paddingTop:7,paddingBottom:7, backgroundColor:'#fff'}}>
               <Text style={{fontSize:13}}> {this.state.data.elapsed}</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={{flex: 1,paddingTop:7,paddingBottom:7, marginLeft:2, backgroundColor:'#000'}}>
               <Text style={{fontSize:13}}></Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          <Text style={{color:"#FFF"}}>{} </Text>
         </View>
         <View style={styles.containerInfo}>
           <ScrollableTabView style={{marginTop: 1}} initialPage={0} renderTabBar={() => <CustomTabBar/>} >
            <View tabLabel='Tab #1'>
             <Text>My</Text>
            </View>
            <View tabLabel='Tab #2'>
            <Text>favorite</Text>
            </View>
            <View tabLabel='Tab #3'>
            <Text>favorite</Text>
            </View>
            <View tabLabel='Tab #4'>
            <Text>favorite</Text>
            </View>
            </ScrollableTabView>
         </View>
      </View>
    )
}
```

[A simple demo in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/loving-raman-vfzlk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FUser.js&theme=dark)

Comment: Is stil not working. in the render if i do this `this.state.data.awayTeam`is working but not this `this.state.data.awayTeam.logo`. It seems that i can access to the first child of data but i can't get all the tree

Comment: @YohanZenou may be logo is coming null from your api

Comment: not because like i said in the getFixture function when i make my api call if at the end of the function i do `this.state.data.awayTeam.logo ` and is working .. the things is i can't access to the all array in my render only the first tree

Comment: @YohanZenou it is normal,  in the first render the data is not available.

Comment: @YohanZenou I updated the answer to explain more,  you can console.log after the null check,  you can check the answer.

Comment: But i need to use this data `this.state.data.awayTeam.logo` in my render in a View and i dont understand why i dont have access

Comment: @YohanZenou I already gave the answer, we have 2 return, in the first return we return immediately since the data is not ready,  in the second return  you will return you current return. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: I update your anwser, please see the updated answer @SuleymanSah Thanks

Comment: @YohanZenou  just try my code in the answer, and see if it works.

Comment: i tried but is not working, i put the error in image in your awnser. Like a said to you if i do this.state.data.awayTeam, its works but when i add this.state.data.awayTeam.logo is not working

Comment: @YohanZenou it clearly means that this.state.data.awayTeam.logo is null? What displays in console when you console.log(this.state.data.awayTeam) ?

Comment: I edit you awnser with a new screenShot that show you what i get when i do this.state.data.awayTeam

Comment: @YohanZenou can you paste your full component code here https://pastebin.com and share with me?

Comment: @– SuleymanSah , Yes sure. I did 2 pastebin, 1 https://pastebin.com/4RQTnpeY with my code and another one with myfile with data that i use for fetch api  https://pastebin.com/7Z88fLTC

Comment: @YohanZenou are you sure those are the component code and data? The data is different, there is no teamAway field there.

Comment: yes i told you that i change de data from your example, anyway i got a problem with my FETCH ! But now is working with your solution when i put a loading, after its show me the value ! but its mean for every loading page we have to put a loader ? we can store in cache the first time and if the user come back get it from cache ? Anyway Thanks you very much for your solution and Help !

Answer (score 0):

Try to log in the setState callback like this

```
   this.setState({
      data:reponseJson,
      isLoading:false
   }, () => {
      console.log(this.state.data.awayTeam.logo)
 })
```

Comment: In the getFixture function i can access to `this.state.data.awayTeam.logo`, but not in the render, i update my code upper. Thanks for help !